# SwiftUI: Animate layout changes when using Layout (iOS 16/macOS 13)

Tags: swiftui

I'm using the new `Layout` protocol and try to animate the views when the layout changes. My layout it similar to this example and does not require any arguments from the parent view (so there are no states that are passed into it): https://swiftwithmajid.com/2022/11/16/building-custom-layout-in-swiftui-basics/

So far I was only able to do it by using the `.animation` modifier on `Layout` which triggers a deprecation warning:

```
MyLayout {
    ...
}
.animation(.default)
```

What is the correct way to do this? There seems to be nothing I can pass as `value` in the `animation` modifier to get rid of the deprecation warning. I also tried using `withAnimation` in `placeSubviews` but that does not work.

EDIT: Added link to example layout.

Here's the full code from [Majid's tutorial](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2022/11/16/building-custom-layout-in-swiftui-basics/) + animation modifier:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        FlowLayout {
            ForEach(0..<5) { _ in
                Group {
                    Text("Hello")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                    Text("World")
                        .font(.title)
                    Text("!!!")
                        .font(.title3)
                }
                .border(Color.red)
            }
        }
        .animation(.default)
    }
}

struct FlowLayout: Layout {
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        let sizes = subviews.map { $0.sizeThatFits(.unspecified) }

        var totalHeight: CGFloat = 0
        var totalWidth: CGFloat = 0

        var lineWidth: CGFloat = 0
        var lineHeight: CGFloat = 0

        for size in sizes {
            if lineWidth + size.width > proposal.width ?? 0 {
                totalHeight += lineHeight
                lineWidth = size.width
                lineHeight = size.height
            } else {
                lineWidth += size.width
                lineHeight = max(lineHeight, size.height)
            }

            totalWidth = max(totalWidth, lineWidth)
        }

        totalHeight += lineHeight

        return .init(width: totalWidth, height: totalHeight)
    }

    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        let sizes = subviews.map { $0.sizeThatFits(.unspecified) }

        var lineX = bounds.minX
        var lineY = bounds.minY
        var lineHeight: CGFloat = 0

        for index in subviews.indices {
            if lineX + sizes[index].width > (proposal.width ?? 0) {
                lineY += lineHeight
                lineHeight = 0
                lineX = bounds.minX
            }

            subviews[index].place(
                at: .init(
                    x: lineX + sizes[index].width / 2,
                    y: lineY + sizes[index].height / 2
                ),
                anchor: .center,
                proposal: ProposedViewSize(sizes[index])
            )

            lineHeight = max(lineHeight, sizes[index].height)
            lineX += sizes[index].width
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself which value (usually a state var or observedObject) in your view makes the view change? Thats the one you can use in `.animation`

Comment: It's the size of `MyLayout` itself that changes the layout within. I could get this by wrapping it in a `GeometryReader` but this would defeat the purpose of using `Layout` which adapts its content automatically based on its own size.

Comment: Understood. Without seeing more of your code it's difficult to see from where Layout takes its size restrictions or changes. In any case this is a great source with examples: https://swiftui-lab.com/layout-protocol-part-1/

Comment: Thanks, that's a good article. Looked at the animation part in the advanced section and the animation there is triggered by a state change in a `withAnimation` block. This state is passed as an argument into the layout. My situation is more like this example: https://swiftwithmajid.com/2022/11/16/building-custom-layout-in-swiftui-basics/ There is no external argument necessary (so no state in the parent), the layout only depends on the subview sizes, the proposed view size and the bounds and is created in the layout itself.

Comment: Without a viable example it is just guessing.

Comment: Added the code from the link as example. If you run this on macOS and resize the window, the animation works, but `.animation` triggers a deprecation warning.

Answer (score 1):

So the animation is dependent on the content size, especially its width. You can get that with a `GeometryReader` and use its width as the animation value.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            FlowLayout {
                ForEach(0..<5) { _ in
                    Group {
                        Text("Hello")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                        Text("World")
                            .font(.title)
                        Text("!!!")
                            .font(.title3)
                    }
                    .border(Color.red)
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center) // to balance the GeometryReader effect
            .animation(.default, value: geo.size.width)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This likely works but the whole point of `Layout` is to stop using `GeometryReader`

Comment: I agree, but I don't see another way of getting the changed content size. Maybe a binding into `FlowLayout`, but that feels even weirder ...

Comment: Agreed, I wonder the toll it takes on performance though.